# Gremlin query (SQL self-join)

Tags: graph, gremlin, graph-databases, self-join

I'm quite new to Gremlin, I've been practicing a bit with [this guide](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html), but when it comes to writing more complex queries I clearly haven't got the hang of it yet. To put you in context, I'm trying to answer a question that in SQL can easily be cracked with a self-join.

Imagine the following simplified graph:

[image]

As you can see, there are two types of entities in the graph: Routes and Legs. A Route is made of 1+ Legs following a particular order (specified in the edge), and a Leg can be in several Routes.

The question I want to answer is: *which routes travel from one country to another, and then back to the previous country?*

In the case of the graph above, Route 1 goes from ES to FR in the first Leg, and from FR to ES in the third Leg, so the output of the query would look like:

```
=> Route id: 1
=> Leg1 order: 1
=> Leg1 id: 1
=> Leg2 order: 3
=> Leg2 id: 3
```

If I had the following relational table:

```
route_id   leg_id   order  source_country   destination_country
1          1        1      ES               FR
1          2        2      FR               FR
1          3        3      FR               ES
```

I could get the desired output with the following query:

```
SELECT
  a.route_id
  ,a.leg_id
  ,a.order
  ,b.leg_id
  ,b.order
FROM Routes a
JOIN Routes b
  ON a.route_id = b.route_id
  AND a.source_country = b.destination_country
  AND a.destination_country = b.source_country
WHERE a.source_country <> a.destination_country;
```

When it comes to writing it in Gremlin, I'm really not quite sure how to start. My inexperience makes me want to perform a self-join as well, but even then I didn't get very far:

```
g.V().hasLabel('Route').as('a').V().hasLabel('Route').as('b').where('a', eq('b')).and(join 'a' edges&legs with 'b' edges&legs)...
```

And that's about it, because I don't know how to reference *a* again as an object that can be traversed to look for the edges and legs connected to the routes.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated, it could definitely happen that this problem can be solved in a simpler way as well :)

Thanks,
Béntor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With graphs you should try to think of terms of "navigating connected things" rather than "joining disparate things" because with a graph the things are already joined explicitly. It also helps to think in terms of streams of things being lazily evaluated (i.e. objects going from one Gremlin step to the next).

First of all, the picture is nice but it's always more helpful to provide some sample data in the form of a Gremlin script like this:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('route').property('rid',1).as('r1').
  addV('route').property('rid',2).as('r2').
  addV('route').property('rid',3).as('r3').
  addV('leg').property('lid',1).property('source','ES').property('dest','FR').as('l1').
  addV('leg').property('lid',2).property('source','FR').property('dest','FR').as('l2').
  addV('leg').property('lid',3).property('source','FR').property('dest','ES').as('l3').
  addV('leg').property('lid',4).property('source','ES').property('dest','FR').as('l4').
  addV('leg').property('lid',5).property('source','FR').property('dest','FR').as('l5').
  addV('leg').property('lid',6).property('source','FR').property('dest','US').as('l6').
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l1').property('order',1).
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l2').property('order',2).
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l3').property('order',3).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l4').property('order',1).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l5').property('order',2).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l6').property('order',3).
  addE('has_leg').from('r2').to('l2').property('order',1).iterate()
```

Your question was:

> which routes travel from one country to another, and then back to the previous country?

Note that I added some extra data that didn't meet the requirements of that question to be sure my traversal was working properly. I suppose I assumed that you were open to getting routes that just stayed in the country like a leg that just went from "FR" to FR" as it started in "FR" and ended in that "previous country". I guess I could revise this further to do that if you really needed me to, but for now I will stick with that assumption since you're just learning.

After considering the data and reading that question I immediately thought, let's find the routes which you did well enough and then let's just see what it takes to get the start leg of the trip and the end leg of the trip for that route:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('route').
......1>   map(outE('has_leg').
......2>       order().by('order').
......3>       union(limit(1).inV().values('source'), tail().inV().values('dest')).
......4>       fold())
==>[ES,ES]
==>[FR,FR]
==>[ES,US]
```

So, I find a "route" vertex with `hasLabel('route')` and then I convert each into a `List` of the start and end country (i.e. a pair where the first item is the "source" country and the second item is the "dest" country). To do that I traverse outgoing "has_leg" edges, order them. Once ordered I grab the first edge in the stream (i.e with `limit(1)`) and traverse to the incoming "leg" vertex and grab its "source" value and do the same for the last incoming vertex of the edge (i.e. with `tail()`) but this time grab its "dest" value. We then use `fold()` to push that two item stream from `union()` into a `List`. Again, because this all happens inside of `map()` we are effectively doing it for each "route" vertex so we get three pairs as a result.

With that output we just now need to compare the start/end values in the pairs to determine which represent a route starting and ending in the same country.

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('route').
......1>   filter(outE('has_leg').
......2>          order().by('order').
......3>          fold().
......4>          project('start','end').
......5>            by(unfold().limit(1).inV().values('source')).
......6>            by(unfold().tail().inV().values('dest')).
......7>          where('start', eq('end'))).
......8>   elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:route,rid:1]
==>[id:2,label:route,rid:2]
```

At line 1, note that we changed `map()` to `filter()`. I only used `map()` initially so that I could see the results of what I was traversing before I worried about how to use those results to get rid of the data I didn't want. That's a common practice with Gremlin as you build more and more complexity in your traversals. So we are now ready to apply a `filter()` to each "route" vertex. I imagine that there are a number of ways to do this, but I chose to gather all the ordered edges into a `List` at line 3. I then `project()` that step at line 4 and transform the edge list for both "start" and "end" keys using the associated `by()` modulators. In both cases I must `unfold()` the edge list to a stream and then apply the same `limit(1)` and `tail()` sort of traversal that was explained earlier. The result is a `Map` with "start" and "end" keys which can be compared using `where()` step. As you can see from the result, the third route that started in "ES" and ended in "US" has been filtered away.

I'll expand my answer based on your comment - Since all of my previous data seems to align with your more general case of wanting to find any route that returns to a country in any sense:

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV('route').property('rid',1).as('r1').
  addV('route').property('rid',2).as('r2').
  addV('route').property('rid',3).as('r3').
  addV('route').property('rid',4).as('r4').
  addV('leg').property('lid',1).property('source','ES').property('dest','FR').as('l1').
  addV('leg').property('lid',2).property('source','FR').property('dest','FR').as('l2').
  addV('leg').property('lid',3).property('source','FR').property('dest','ES').as('l3').
  addV('leg').property('lid',4).property('source','ES').property('dest','FR').as('l4').
  addV('leg').property('lid',5).property('source','FR').property('dest','FR').as('l5').
  addV('leg').property('lid',6).property('source','FR').property('dest','US').as('l6').
  addV('leg').property('lid',7).property('source','ES').property('dest','FR').as('l7').
  addV('leg').property('lid',8).property('source','FR').property('dest','CA').as('l8').
  addV('leg').property('lid',9).property('source','CA').property('dest','US').as('l9').
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l1').property('order',1).
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l2').property('order',2).
  addE('has_leg').from('r1').to('l3').property('order',3).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l4').property('order',1).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l5').property('order',2).
  addE('has_leg').from('r3').to('l6').property('order',3).
  addE('has_leg').from('r4').to('l7').property('order',1).
  addE('has_leg').from('r4').to('l8').property('order',2).
  addE('has_leg').from('r4').to('l9').property('order',3).
  addE('has_leg').from('r2').to('l2').property('order',1).iterate()
```

If I have this right the newly added "rid=4" route should be filtered as its route never revisits the same country. I think this bit of Gremlin is even easier than what I suggested previously because now we just need to look for unique routes which means that if we satisfy one of these two situations then we've found a route we care about:

1. There is one leg and it starts/ends in the same country
2. There are multiple legs and if the number of times that country appears in the route exceeds 2 (because we are taking into account "source" and "dest")

Here's the Gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('route').
......1>   filter(out('has_leg').
......2>          union(values('source'), 
......3>                values('dest')).
......4>          groupCount().
......5>          or(select(values).unfold().is(gt(2)),
......6>             count(local).is(1))).
......7>   elementMap()
==>[id:0,label:route,rid:1]
==>[id:2,label:route,rid:2]
==>[id:4,label:route,rid:3]
```

If you understood my earlier explanations of the code, then you likely follow everything up to line 5 where we take the `Map` produced by the `groupCount()` on country names and apply the two filter conditions I just described. At line 5, we apply the second condition which extracts the values from the `Map` (i.e. the counts of the number of times each country appears) and detects if any are greater than 2. On line 6, we count the entries in the `Map` which maps to the first condition. Note that we use `local` there because we aren't counting the `Map`-objects in the stream but the entries within the `Map` (i.e. local to the `Map`).

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your detailed answer, very instructional examples on how to approach Gremlin queries. Your solution indeed produces the right output to the example in my post; however, I was hoping we could figure out the query for the more general case. Imagine a route  ES->FR->DE->FR->IT. It went from FR to DE and back to FR in the mid legs, and the initial and final countries are not equal. I think we would need to traverse (or compare) the edges and Legs in some kind of order, what do you think?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think that your request to further generalize the result might have made this query even easier to write and understand. There might yet be other ways to accomplish this and wouldn't be surprised to see other answers with different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it's useful here is a similar example I was playing with before I saw Stephen had already answered. This uses the air-routes data set from the tutorial. The first example starts specifically at LHR. The second looks at all airports. I assumed a constant of 2 segments. You could change that by modifying the query, and, as Stephen mentioned, there are many ways you could approach this.

```
gremlin> g.V().has('code','LHR').as('a').
......1>       out().
......2>       where(neq('a')).by('country').
......3>       repeat(out().simplePath()).times(1).
......4>       where(eq('a')).by('country').
......5>       path().
......6>         by(values('country','code').fold()).
......7>       limit(5) 

==>[[UK,LHR],[MA,CMN],[UK,LGW]]
==>[[UK,LHR],[MA,CMN],[UK,MAN]]
==>[[UK,LHR],[MA,TNG],[UK,LGW]]
==>[[UK,LHR],[CN,CTU],[UK,LGW]]
==>[[UK,LHR],[PT,FAO],[UK,BHX]]  



gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('airport').as('a').
......1>       out().
......2>       where(neq('a')).by('country').
......3>       repeat(out().simplePath()).times(1).
......4>       where(eq('a')).by('country').
......5>       path().
......6>         by(values('country','code').fold()).
......7>       limit(5) 

==>[[US,ATL],[CL,SCL],[US,DFW]]
==>[[US,ATL],[CL,SCL],[US,IAH]]
==>[[US,ATL],[CL,SCL],[US,JFK]]
==>[[US,ATL],[CL,SCL],[US,LAX]]
==>[[US,ATL],[CL,SCL],[US,MCO]]
```

For your specific example, the technique Stephen used taking advantage of segments having an order number is much nicer. The air-routes data set does not have a concept of a segment but thought this might be of some interest as you start exploring Gremlin more.